# Choose the right analysis

Tags: r, statistics

I have dataset in R that contains 2 group `good` and `bad`. The group good contains users that have a long lifetime and users in bad have a short lifetime.

So `good` contains `game_id` and `game_played`. For example `good$game_id==1` (game 1) has been played `good$game_played==12.5` hours.

I want to investigate if there are a difference between good and bad and see which game_id's that make the difference between good and bad.

I have 20 game_id's so I don't need Principal Component Analysis to make a reduction of game_id's. How should one make an analysis to see if some game_id's makes the difference between `good` and `bad` ?

So in R we get for `good`

an output like this:

```
game_id   game_played
6         18.3
14        2.1
4         0.6
1         1.0
2         1.4
3         0.1
5         0.4
7         1.2
8         1.2
9         3.1
10        1.7
11        11.6
12        0.2
13        5.4
15        4.3
16        12.4
17        8.2
18        7.0
19        3.4
20        4.6
```

where `game_id` is the name of the game and `game_played` is the hours the game has been played in data `good`. For `bad` we have a similar output with difference values.

Comment: Could you provide a concrete example of the dataset containing `good` and `bad`? And what do you mean by "difference" between `good` and 'bad'? Are you looking for `game_id`'s that appear frequently in `good` and rarely in `bad` or vice versa?

Comment: I have given an example. I want to investigate if there a game has been played much in 'good' and therefore causes these users to play more. Similar I want to investigate if there is a game in 'bad' that causes these users to stop playing.

Comment: `head(good,3)` is to short. `head(good,100)` and `head(bad,100)` would be better. Is the `game_played` column relevant for the question?

Comment: game_played simply tells us how many hours a game_id has been played in a fixed group (good or bad). If we have a high game_played for game_id==6 in good but a low game_played for game_id==6 in bad this must indicate that game_id maybe course the difference between the two groups.

Comment: It seems that every game_id appears only once in `good` and `bad`. So `game_played` summerizes the hours the game_id has been played by the individual players. Is it the average or the sum? Are there as many good players as bad players?  And is the number of times a game_id has been played the same for all game_id's? The larger this number the better is an estimate if that game_id makes a difference.

Comment: It is the average per "player" in a group and there are the same number of good players as bad players. game_played is the number of times a game has been played divided by the number of players in that group.